# Sticky image with uikit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to recreate the following [page](https://www.scenic.com.au/tour/gems-of-the-danube/7883#pricing-availability) with the use of UIKIT css frame work. Till now I've accomplished this far: [Link](https://codepen.io/Kajol2608/pen/ePZjbb)

```css
.sticky-wrapper{
    background-color:#fff;
}
#content-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
#sticky-image img{
  position: absolute;
  top:-230px;
}
```

I'm finding quite hard to change the position of image while srolling down.
Can anyone suggest how can I get this image working like in the template that I'm looking.

Answer (score 0):

here
you can use default Element of Uikit. if you are using Uikit Framework, 
Please Prefer 
[UiKit](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/sticky.html),
Eg. `<div data-uk-sticky>...</div>`